# Как в русском языке появились совершенный и несовершенный виды?

Tags: историческая-грамматика

я даю уроки русского языка во Франции, одна ученица-француженка меня спросила, каким образом сформировались в русском языке совершенный и несовершенный виды. Я практик, а тут вопрос касается истории языка.
Может ли кто-то дать квалифицированный ответ?
В Интернете ответа не могу найти. Заранее спасибо, Галина Дезарно.

Comment: Такие мысли: прежде, чем пускаться в объяснения, я бы выяснил поточнее, что конкретно ученица хочет узнать. То есть, что есть "вид" в её системе понятий. Осознаёт ли она, что в её родном языке также есть категория вида, или же её этому никогда не учили? Что вполне возможно, так как существуют различные подходы к преподаванию (французам) фр. грамматики в том, что касается "Temps et aspects", и на уровне школы подход поменялся относительно недавно.  А на вопрос, в том виде, в котором он задан, вам ответили более чем...

Answer (score 3):

Категория вида в русском языке связана с развитием системы времен русского глагола.

1)  Система глагольных времен 10 - 11 вв. включали в себя 1 парадигму форм наст./буд. времени, 4 парадигмы форм прошедшего времени и две парадигмы будущего времени. Каждая парадигма употреблялась строго закономерно для обозначения определенных отношения действия к моменту речи.

Общий путь эволюции форм прошедшего времени в древнерусском языке в 12 – 14 вв. сводится к двум основным моментам:

а) утрата особых образований имперфекта и аориста, а также формы плюсквамперфекта;

б) становление единой формы, восходящей к старому перфекту, утерявшему свой аналитический способ образования, что в конечном итоге было связано с развитием и становлением категории вида в истории русского языка.

**Все те обозначения способов прошедшего действия, которые когда-то находили свое выражение в особой форме прошедшего времени, стали выражаться с помощью видовых противопоставлений или лексическими средствами, определяющими общее значение контекста.**

2) К 14 -15 вв. складываются три отдельные восточнославянские народности. В области временных глагольных форм язык восточнославянской народности в общих чертах характеризуется тем, что основные процессы перестройки системы форм времени уже завершились. В области форм настоящего времени почти полностью было утрачено атематическое спряжение, установились новые флексии в тематических спряжениях. В области прошедшего времени была полностью утрачена система простых и сложных времен, т.е. **укрепившаяся и развивающаяся категория глагольного вида вытеснила из языка формы аориста и имперфекта и позволила бывшему причастию на -л- в составе старого перфекта (утратившего свой глагол-связку быти в настоящем времени) стать единой формой прошедшего времени.** По существу был утрачен и плюсквамперфект: в преобразованном виде он сохранился лишь в отдельных диалектах. **В области форм будущего времени сформировалась категория простого будущего совершенного вида, что было связано с укреплением видовой корреляции в русском языке, а также категория сложного будущего времени несовершенного вида с использованием конструкции «буду + инфинитив» для выражения этого значения.**

Вид возник и развивался в рамках определенной системы времен. Характерной чертой праславянской, а также временной системы древнерусского языка исходного периода была асимметричность. Эта система имела лишь одну синкретичную недифференцированную форму наст./буд. времени. Ее морфологическое (независимое от контекста) значение состояло из двух равноправных компонентов: значения одновременности с моментом речи и значения следования. Эта форма могла образовываться от любого глагола, как простого, так и приставочного, и конкретное значение настоящего или будущего времени она получала только в контексте.

Морфологическое значение форм аориста и имперфекта, кроме значения предшествования действия моменту речи, включало в себя еще и семантический компонент, определявший характер протекания действия. Однако можно предположить, что в период первоначального возникновения видовых различий формирование и актуализация значения процессуальности, которое легло в основу складывавшегося имперфективного значения, произошли в рамках формы наст./буд. времени. Эта форма вследствие своей синкретичности и многофункциональности для передачи значения процессуальности в плане настоящего нуждалась в контекстных определителях. Поэтому и появилась новая четкая форма со значением только настоящего времени, образованная с помощью глагольных суффиксов и деривационных чередований корневых гласных. **Поскольку абсолютные формы прошедшего времени (аорист и имперфект) именно в своем семантическом компоненте обозначали характер протекания действия, они соответственно могли выражать
первоначальные видовые различия.**

К 14 веку перфект стал единственной формой прошедшего времени, приобретя общее значение предшествования действия моменту речи. Это означало отказ от обозначения формантом времени характера протекания действия. Т.о., была разорвана связь формы времени с видовым значением глагольной основы. Оба члена видовой корреляции стали свободно образовывать формы прошедшего времени.

**Появление и быстрое распространение нового, практически универсального средства имперфективации - суффикса ива/ыва - сделало возможным легкое и быстрое образование форм несовершенного вида от любого приставочного глагола.**

**Постепенно все приставочные глаголы оказались втянутыми в систему видовых корреляций. В связи с этим завершилось формирование значения совершенного вида. Это привело к ликвидации синкретизма формы наст./буд. времени у приставочных глаголов, которые закрепили за собой значение совершенного вида. Форма наст./буд. времени у таких глаголов стала формой простого будущего времени. Вместе с тем члены видовой корреляции получили дополнительное распределение форм наст./буд. времени: коррелят несовершенного вида мог образовывать только форму настоящего времени, коррелят совершенного вида - только форму простого будущего.** **Весьма существенным процессом в развитии видо-временных отношений на протяжении 15 - 17 вв. было создание форм будущего времени у глаголов несовершенного вида. Это позволяет говорить о завершении процесса развития видовой корреляции, так как несовершенный вид получил полную парадигму форм времени.**

Подробнее здесь: https://studfiles.net/preview/5375380/page:12/

Comment: Исчерпывающе, но, боюсь, понятно только специалистам.

Comment: Но ведь просили дать  квалифицированный ответ.

Comment: :) Вовсе нет. Спрашивали, может ли кто его дать. :) А вскоре спрашивающий взял и пропал, так что всё было зря. А вообще на такой вопрос я б, например, неквалифицированно ответил, что в русском языке виды не формировались, а были изначально. Формулировочка-то не продумана..